# Redis cluster: discovery of new master by Java clients

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I've created a Redis cluster with 3 masters and 2 replicas for each master node. Which Java client libraries are able to connect to the cluster (set of master nodes?) and are able to detect the master failover and then able to communicate to the new master?

I used Jedis client library to connect to the Redis cluster:

```
   private static JedisCluster jedisCluster;
   static {
   try {
     Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
     jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 7000));
     jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 7001));
     jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("127.0.0.1", 7002));
     jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
  } catch (Throwable t) {
     t.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

All the clients executing `jedisCluster.incr(KEY);` using this `jedisCluster` start failing when a master goes down. At the cluster level, one of the replicas is promoted to be the new master.

**So, where is the auto detection of the new master(s) by the client?**

Comment: Promoting a replica to master is not instantaneous. It takes a minimal amount of time. Your operations to that downed master in that time will fail. But do your operations fail even after `one of the replicas is promoted to be the new master`?

Comment: Yes. Also, I don't need theories here, which I'm well aware of. My question is very specific. The JedisCluster calls seem to fail after replica promotion.

Would it be possible for you to put a link explaining how actually the new master is recognized by the Jedis library? Or for that matter any other Java based client?

A code snippet would be the precise help.